# Realloc: invalid next size in dynamic vector of structs

Tags: c, vector, realloc

I'm trying to make this code work, but I cannot see why it crashes. It is supposed to read data from a file, and put it sorted (insertion sort) in a vector. proc is a vector of Process_t, proc.name is a char[10], proc[0] is inserted before (hard coded) and num_proc == 1. The first register of the file is catched properly, but then it crashes (just in the realloc()).

```
    size = 1
    while(size > 0)
    {
        // Read a process from the config file and add to the vector in a sorted way
        printf("%d\n", num_proc);
        proc = realloc(proc, sizeof(Process_t)*num_proc);
        printf("%d\n", num_proc);

        size = fscanf(cfgfd, "%hhd %s\n", &hwmodid, buf);
        printf("%d %d %s\n", num_proc, hwmodid, buf);

        i = num_proc-1;
        while(i > 1 && proc[i].hwmodid > hwmodid)
        {
            strcpy(proc[i+1].name, proc[i].name);
            proc[i+1].hwmodid = proc[i].hwmodid;
            proc[i+1].pid = proc[i].pid;
            proc[i+1].fiforfd = proc[i].fiforfd;
            proc[i+1].fifowfd = proc[i].fifowfd;
            proc[i+1].paused = proc[i].paused;
            --i;
        }
        strcpy(proc[i+1].name, buf);
        proc[i+1].hwmodid = hwmodid;
        proc[i+1].pid = -1;
        proc[i+1].fiforfd = -1; 
        proc[i+1].fifowfd = -1;
        proc[i+1].paused = 0;
        ++num_proc;

        printf("%d %s %d %d %d %d %d\n", i, proc[num_proc-1].name, proc[num_proc-1].hwmodid, proc[num_proc-1].pid, proc[num_proc-1].fiforfd, proc[num_proc-1].fifowfd, proc[num_proc-1].paused);
    }
```

Comment: You have allocated memory for `proc` before this? Or initialized `proc` to `NULL`?

Comment: proc has size of 1 struct. I just realized I missed a +1 when reallocating size. Stupid errors are the most difficult to find.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, from MAN: realloc() changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged to the minimum of the  old  and  new  sizes;  newly allocated  memory will be uninitialized.  If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().  If  thearea pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.
NULL is fine, unitialised is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I missed a +1 when reallocating. I was allocating for what I already had (at first I had 1, and was allocating for 1 and inserting 1). The first element of the vector inserted dinamically was put by luck. Stupid mistakes that are difficult to find.